# How to center align nebula grid column group header

Tags: java, grid, nebula

I want to center align the column group text, so provided the SWT.CENTER style while creating the "GridColumnGroup" similar to the way we provide for GridColumn.
However even after providing the CENTER style, column group text is shown Left aligned.

Code I tried:

```
GridColumnGroup columnGroup = new GridColumnGroup(grid,SWT.CENTER);
columnGroup.setText("Column Group");
GridColumn column1 = new GridColumn(columnGroup,SWT.CENTER);
column1.setText("Column 1");
GridColumn column2 = new GridColumn(columnGroup,SWT.CENTER);
column2.setText("Column 2");
```

[Nebula Grid column and column group rendering with above code ]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js3RU.png)
Any idea what I am missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The style `SWT.CENTER` does not propagate to the `GridHeaderRenderer` of the column group. However, [void setHorizontalAlignment​(int alignment)](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/releases/latest/javadoc/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/grid/GridHeaderRenderer.html#setHorizontalAlignment(int)) method of `GridHeaderRenderer` allows you to center the text.

```
columnGroup.getHeaderRenderer().setHorizontalAlignment(SWT.CENTER);
```